# How to test Nhibernate with Nunit?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nhibernate, nunit

Sorry for the repost.

I'm using Nhibernate for ORM and have this class I need to perform unit tests using Nunit:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using NutritionLibrary.Entity;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections;

namespace NutritionLibrary.DAO
{
    public class IngredientDAONHibernate : NutritionLibrary.DAO.IngredientDAO

    {

          private Configuration config;
        private ISessionFactory factory;

        public IngredientDAONHibernate()
        {

                config = new Configuration();
                config.AddClass(typeof(NutritionLibrary.Entity.Ingredient));
                config.AddClass(typeof(Entity.Nutrient));
                config.AddClass(typeof(Entity.NutrientIngredient));
                       factory = config.BuildSessionFactory();

        }


        /// <summary>
        ///  gets the list of ingredients from the db
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>IList of ingredients</returns>
        public System.Collections.Generic.IList<Ingredient> GetIngredientList()
        {
            System.Collections.Generic.IList<Ingredient> ingredients;
            string hql = "from NutritionLibrary.Entity.Ingredient ingredient";

            ISession session = null;
            ITransaction tx = null;

            try
            {
                session = factory.OpenSession();
                tx = session.BeginTransaction();

                IQuery q = session.CreateQuery(hql);

                ingredients = q.List<Ingredient>();
                tx.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (tx != null) tx.Rollback();
                /*if (logger.IsErrorEnabled)
                {
                    logger.Error("EXCEPTION OCCURRED", e);
                }*/

             ingredients = null;
            }
            finally
            {
                session.Close();
                session = null;
                tx = null;
            }

            return ingredients;
        }


    }
}
```

I started with the constructor, but I got a few people advising me its not really necessary. So this is my method that I need to test. It queries the db and gives me a List of ingredient objects. I am having difficulty getting started with how to test the getIngredientList() method. I have this test stub:

```
[TestMethod()]
        public void GetIngredientListTest()
        {
            IngredientDAONHibernate target = new IngredientDAONHibernate(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
            IList<Ingredient> expected = null; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
            IList<Ingredient> actual;
            actual = target.GetIngredientList();
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);

        }
```

I have a lot of other similar methods that I have to test, so if someone could be kind enough to help me get started with this, I will have a basic idea of how to implement unit tests on my other methods.

Once again, thank you for your time and advise.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to explain this myself, the best advice I can give you is learning about and using the [S#arp architecture](http://code.google.com/p/sharp-architecture/), which helps you with setting up the nUnit tests, the DAO and the DAL layer and much more. It also enforces using [NHibernates Best Practices](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/NHibernateBestPractices.aspx) and more. You can read more about the S#arp architecture and how to set it up and run nUnit tests etc, on [Bill McCafferty's blog](http://devlicio.us/blogs/billy_mccafferty/archive/2008/04/21/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-with-nhibernate-and-spring-net.aspx) (also the one maintaining the S#arp libs).

Note: for getting started quickly, the S#arp libs come with a plethora of examples to show you how it's done. And if S#arp seems like too much, you can follow the link on NH Best Practices above, it has quite some notes on how to go about setting up nUnit tests in a unified and generic way.